# change `msg.sender` in solidity and ether.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, ethers.js

I have Smartcontract with solidity . in this smart contract i have function with name `makeMarketItem` .

```
  function makeMarketItem(
        address nftContract,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 price
    ) public payable nonReentrant {
        IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
}
```

I call this function with `ethers` library in nodejs .

Inital this smart contract with `ethers` by this way :

```
static async Initial(): Promise<any> {

    let provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(config.contractConfig.url);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();

    this.tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(NFT.networks['5777'].address, NFT.abi, signer);
    this.dNFT = new ethers.Contract(DNFT.networks['5777'].address, DNFT.abi, signer);

}
```

i want to called that function by this way :

```
 transaction = this.dNFT.makeMarketItem(
                this.tokenContract.address,
                tokenId,
                price,
                {
                    value: listPricing.result
                }
            );
```

**Problem:** I need to change value of `msg.sender` .

How can I change `msg.sender` address ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `.connect()` method is what you're looking for, you can use it to call a contract method from a particular address/signer:

```js
const [owner, addr1] = await ethers.getSigners();
this.dNFT.connect(addr1).makeMarketItem(...);
```